# How to convert from &str to *const i8 *without* libstd and libcore?

Tags: string, operating-system, kernel, rust

I have a scenario where we have an existing (old) operating system written in C, some 15 years ago. Now, we are looking at extending this system, being able to write user-space programs in Rust.

Naturally, because this was recently started, we haven't bothered about porting all of `libstd` to our own OS yet. We are hence using `#![feature(no_std)]`.

Now, I am looking for something that should be reasonably simple: *converting a Rust string into a C-null-terminated string*. Should be simple, but because I am so inexperienced with Rust I haven't (yet) been able to figure it out.

For the sake of this experience, it's enough to impose certain limits (like, max 1024 byte long strings; anything else gets truncated). (We do have memory allocation in place but I haven't bothered trying to handle memory allocation from Rust yet)

Here is my feeble attempt so far:

```
pub struct CString {
    buffer: [i8; 1024]
}

impl CString {
    pub fn new(s: &str) -> CString {
        CString {
            buffer: CString::to_c_string(s)
        }
    }

    fn to_c_string(s: &str) -> [i8; 1024] {
        let buffer: [i8; 1024];
        let mut i = 0;

        // TODO: ignore the risk for buffer overruns for now. :)
        // TODO: likewise with UTF8; assume that we are ASCII-only.
        for c in s.chars() {
            buffer[i] = c as i8;
            i = i + 1;
        }

        buffer[s.len()] = '\0' as i8;
        buffer;
    }

    pub fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const i8 {    
        // TODO: Implement. The line below doesn't even compile.
        self.buffer as *const i8
    }
}
```

The core problem here is the type-casting in `as_ptr`. How do you do it in Rust? Also, are there any other issues with this code, apart from the obvious ones? (broken UTF8 non-ASCII character handling, totally stupid if the string is longer than 1024 characters... :)

Huge thanks in advance! This **must** be something fairly obvious...

---

**Update**: Based on the the answer by Will Fischer (thanks!), I changed my `as_ptr` method to look like this:

```
pub fn as_ptr(&self) -> *const i8 {
    &self.buffer as *const i8
}
```

The code now compiles, but it doesn't link:

```
virtio_net_pci.0.rs:(.text._ZN6system8c_string7CString3new20hbfc6c6db748de66bpaaE+0x31): undefined reference to `memset'
virtio_net_pci.0.rs:(.text._ZN6system8c_string7CString3new20hbfc6c6db748de66bpaaE+0x14f): undefined reference to `memcpy'
virtio_net_pci.0.rs:(.text._ZN6system8c_string7CString3new20hbfc6c6db748de66bpaaE+0x174): undefined reference to `panicking::panic_bounds_check::h0b7be17a72a754b5P6E'
virtio_net_pci.0.rs:(.text._ZN6system8c_string7CString3new20hbfc6c6db748de66bpaaE+0x18c): undefined reference to `panicking::panic_bounds_check::h0b7be17a72a754b5P6E'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The `memset` and `memcpy` stuff is easy to fix. The bounds checking I assume is implemented in `libcore` - any way to get that working without linking to libcore? (which would probably be a reasonable thing anyway...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of casting the buffer, cast a reference to the buffer. [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20buffer%3A%20[i8%3B%201024]%20%3D%20[42%3B%201024]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20ptr%3A%20*const%20i8%20%3D%20%26buffer%20as%20*const%20i8%3B%0A%20%20%20%20unsafe%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%7D%22%2C%20*ptr.offset%2830%29%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D&version=stable)

```
fn main() {
    let buffer: [i8; 1024] = [42; 1024];
    let ptr: *const i8 = &buffer as *const i8;
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", *ptr.offset(30));
    }
}
```

Have you tried getting your code to work with [libcore](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/)? It's a subset of the standard library that covers everything that doesn't need OS support. You can get string manipulation functions through that.

Comment: Important side note: since `as_ptr` consumes `self`, this will get the code to compile, but the return value will be a dangling pointer.

Comment: Which as_ptr is that? Sounds like a misunderstanding.

Comment: `pub fn as_ptr(self) -> *const i8` from OP's sample code. Since it takes `self` by value, the `CString` instance will be deallocated at the end of the function, which means you're returning a pointer to freed memory.

Comment: Thanks @WillFischer/@fjh! That was a pure stupidity on my behalf (I'm very green as far as Rust is concerned, which one can tell by looking at my foul code. :) The OP has been changed in this regard now.